# Recording with X32 + S16

Tags: mixer, behringer

I have a setup with the [Behringer X32 mixer](http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Mixers/Digital-Mixers/X32/p/P0ASF), plus 2 of the [S16 stagebox](http://www.music-group.com/Categories/Behringer/Mixers/I-O-Interfaces/S16/p/P0AJA).

When I use only the X32 I can connect to my computer (Firewire or USB) and record 32 channels without problem.

When I use the X32 in combination with the S16 I cannot record. Sound comes in the X32 but audio-card receives no audio signal.

Is there any known issue, limitation that is known for this setup?
If the setup blocks the X32 audio-card functionality is there any other idea of how I can record at the same time? maybe via optical ADAT?

Feedback, experience or instructions if this is possible would be interesting to hear about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I got my mistake.

It is possible to use the setup to do live sound as well as record. The missing part was setting up the routing in the *card out* menu. That is where we choose what the sound card will be using, and sending via USB/Firewire to the computer. I set it to the AES50 ports A1 to A32.

The setup should look like this:

[image]